# MS GP Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I’ve been tasked to create a web service that will monitor record creation in a Dynamic GP Database. The technology proposed is MS GP (Great Plains). I’m very new to this technology and somewhere along the road in my research I’m missing information on getting started  (I’m a well-seasoned C# WinForms Developer). I have downloaded and installed the MS Dynamics GP SDK, but when I create a web service in visual studio I see no references to any of the MS Dynamics libraries in Visual Studio…  I could not find any examples online, where do I start?

I’m particularly interested in monitoring the event [Created] in the GP database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk to GP databases, I highly recommend the EConnect training docs.  This will contain the DLLs you are looking for to reference things inside GP.  Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973822.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I did do some reading in that section, However the SDK I installed from the MS site didn’t seem to deploy the Dynamic GP assemblies required for development… This is where I’m mainly confused…

Comment: Ahh.  The eConnect SDK is installed from the GP installation disc.  Find your sys admin for a copy.  Or, if you have an account with the online Microsoft Business Solutions website, you can download it there.  They make it extra hard to get these things so that you have to go through certified MBS consultants.

Comment: Great, when the CIO gets back i'm now armed with some great questions...lol, thanks! I'll have a response soon.

Comment: Sice this lead me to the right direction i'm marking it as answer. Thanks